# How can check if particular application/software is installed in Mac OS

Tags: macos, installation

I want to check if particular application is installed in Mac OS using Perl/Shell scripts. 
I am writing package using PackageMaker in which i need to check user machine for few applications before installing the application.
So am planning to write a script that will check this for me. 
Please advice if I can perform this in better way.

Comment: Maybe look for the application .app file in /Applications?

Comment: Applescript might be an option to test if it could launch the app. Don't know is that violate you perl/shell though.

Comment: @ JoePasq , User can install the application in other location as well

Answer (score 13):

To complement [@Bavarious' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024765/45375):

Here are **generic `bash` functions** that expand on testing just whether an application is installed by returning either an application's path or its bundle ID, if installed. If you place them in your bash profile, they may come in handy for interactive use, too.

Either function can still also be used as a test for whether an application is installed; e.g.:
`if ! whichapp 'someApp' &>/dev/null; then ... # not installed`

Neither function is case-sensitive, and, when specifying a *name*, the `.app` suffix is optional.
Note, however, that *localized* names are *not* recognized.

### `whichapp`

A function for locating applications by *either* bundle ID *or* name.
Returns the application's path, if found; otherwise, reports an error.

Examples:

- `whichapp finder            # -> '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/'`
- `whichapp com.apple.finder  # -> '/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/'`

### `bundleid`

Given an application's name, returns its bundle ID.

Example:

- `bundleid finder            # -> 'com.apple.finder'`

---

**Implementation note:** In the AppleScript code, it's tempting to bypass the Finder context and simply use e.g. `application [id] <appNameOrBundleId>` and `path to application [id] <appNameOrBundleId>` in the global context, but the problem is that that invariably *launches* the targeted application, which is undesired.

### source: whichapp

```sh
whichapp() {
  local appNameOrBundleId=$1 isAppName=0 bundleId
  # Determine whether an app *name* or *bundle ID* was specified.
  [[ $appNameOrBundleId =~ \.[aA][pP][pP]$ || $appNameOrBundleId =~ ^[^.]+$ ]] && isAppName=1
  if (( isAppName )); then # an application NAME was specified
    # Translate to a bundle ID first.
    bundleId=$(osascript -e "id of application \"$appNameOrBundleId\"" 2>/dev/null) ||
      { echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: Application with specified name not found: $appNameOrBundleId" 1>&2; return 1; }
  else # a BUNDLE ID was specified
    bundleId=$appNameOrBundleId
  fi
    # Let AppleScript determine the full bundle path.
  fullPath=$(osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to POSIX path of (get application file id \"$bundleId\" as alias)" 2>/dev/null ||
    { echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: Application with specified bundle ID not found: $bundleId" 1>&2; return 1; })
  printf '%s\n' "$fullPath"
  # Warn about /Volumes/... paths, because applications launched from mounted
  # devices aren't persistently installed.
  if [[ $fullPath == /Volumes/* ]]; then
    echo "NOTE: Application is not persistently installed, due to being located on a mounted volume." >&2 
  fi
}
```

**Note**: The function also finds applications launched from a *mounted volume* in a given session<sup>Thanks, [Wonder Dog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2498116/wonder-dog).</sup>, but since such applications aren't persistently installed (not persistently registered with the macOS Launch Services), a *warning* is issued in that event.
If desired, you can easily modify the function to report an error instead.

### source: bundleid

```sh
bundleid() {
  osascript -e "id of application \"$1\"" 2>/dev/null || 
    { echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: Application with specified name not found: $1" 1>&2; return 1; }
}
```

Comment: This method also lists applications in Trash or mounted volumes used to install the application. I don't think these should be considered "installed" applications.

Comment: @WonderDog: Good point re apps from mounted volumes: I've modified the function to report a warning in that case, but you can easily change that to an error, if desired (or filter out `/Volumes/...` matches after the fact). On macOS 10.13.6 I don't see the symptom with respect to a trashed application - what version are you on?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `system_profiler` command for this. Try something like this:

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType | grep AppName
```

Comment: This is good to know, but probably too slow for use in a script interested only in a particular application.

Answer (score 7):

The following bash script uses AppleScript to check if an application is installed, based on [a solution by Michael Pilat](http://www.mikepilat.com/blog/2010/04/determining-if-an-application-is-installed-with-applescript/):

```
#!/bin/bash

APPLESCRIPT=`cat <<EOF
on run argv
  try
    tell application "Finder"
      set appname to name of application file id "$1"
      return 1
    end tell
  on error err_msg number err_num
    return 0
  end try
end run
EOF`

retcode=`osascript -e "$APPLESCRIPT"`
exit $retcode
```

The script expects an application identifier (e.g. com.apple.preview). After executing the script, `retcode` contains 1 if the application is installed and 0 if the application isn’t installed. The script also returns `retcode`.

For example:

```
$ ./appinst.sh com.apple.preview
$ echo $?
1
$
```

or

```
$ ./appinst.sh nonono
$ echo $?
0
$
```

Comment: Cool stuff. Here's a more concise variant: a bash function that takes a bundle ID and returns the app's path if found, an empty string otherwise: `getAppPathByBundleId() { osascript -e 'try' -e 'tell application "Finder" to return POSIX path of (path to application file id "'"$1"'") as text' -e 'end try'; }`. See also my answer for testing by app name and finding an app's bundle ID. (Note that it's tempting, as I've just learned the hard way, to bypass the Finder context and simply use e.g. `application id "com.apple.reminders"`, which works, but _implicitly launches_ the specified app.)

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, all third party apps are installed within the Applications folder. The simplest way would just be to grep through that.

```
ls /Applications/ | grep -i APP_NAME
```

Just replace APP_NAME with whatever you're looking for. The "-i" makes the grep case insensitive so barring some major spelling errors if it's installed it'll list out the file. Otherwise it'll return nothing.

Comment: As you hint at, applications can be in other locations, notably `~/Applications`, but even in other, non-standard locations. Therefore, @Bavarious' solution is preferable.

Comment: but for example if I install a Cmake which is not in the application folder, in this case, how I could check if cmake is installed, further  more, how I could proper remove cmake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppleScript to ask for the "ID" of the application. (But see the update below for a more reliable way!)

Here is an example that can be used in a Bash script to check if "QuickTime Player 7" is available:

```sh
if osascript -e 'id of application "QuickTime Player 7"' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Yes, QT 7 is available"
else
    echo "No, QT 7 not found"
fi
```

The application name is not case-sensitive, so "quicktime player 7" also works.

If you want to use a Bash variable for the app name in your script, be aware that AppleScript requires double-quotes around the app name. So you would need to write something like this, escaping the double quotes:

```sh
app='QuickTime Player 7'
if osascript -e "id of application \"$app\"" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   #...
fi
```

**Update:**

However, as I discovered with this particular example which I was using, the application name may change! On a different machine, the same QT 7 app was named "QuickTime 7 Pro" instead of "QuickTime Player 7".

So the more reliable solution is to know the ID of the application, which should remain the same across different installs. Then you can check for the existence of that ID.

```sh
if osascript -e 'exists application id "com.apple.quicktimeplayer"' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    ((debug)) && echo "OK: Quicktime 7 found" >&2
else
    echo "ERROR: Cannot find Quicktime 7" >&2
fi
```