# Using Electron / Node.js, how can I detect all installed browsers on macOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

I'm trying to find a way to list all installed web browsers in my macOS Electron app. What would be the best way to do this? Or... I'm happy to maintain a list of possible browsers but need a way to check they are present.

Comment: Maybe a combination of [this applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024765/2016129) and a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=applescript&page=1&ranking=popularity) that can execute those for you.

Comment: why dont you use the npm package called as ' fetch-installed-software' ?

Comment: `fetch-installed-software` only supports Windows and looks to be unmaintained now. I'm now using `mdfind 'kMDItemContentType == "com.apple.application-bundle" && kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == "${appId}"'` to detect a browser by bundle ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to [create a child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) which executes a command to receive the currently installed applications. Luckely macOS offers the [system_profiler](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) utility for doing so and even better it allows XML export via the `-xml` argument. But be aware it is by far not the fastest function.

You'll need to get the buffer chunks from the subprocess callback, encode it as utf-8 and then parse the XML string through something like `xml2js`. After that it is a simple check of the property of the browser is checked or not.

> Updated code by Will Stone

```js
import jp from 'jsonpath' // for easier json traversal

import { spawn } from 'child_process'
import parser from 'xml2json'

const sp = spawn('system_profiler', ['-xml', 'SPApplicationsDataType'])

let profile = ''

const browsers = [
  'Brave',
  'Chromium',
  'Firefox',
  'Google Chrome',
  'Maxthon',
  'Opera',
  'Safari',
  'SeaMonkey',
  'TorBrowser',
  'Vivaldi'
]

sp.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
sp.stdout.on('data', data => {
  profile += data // gather chunked data
})

sp.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
})

sp.on('close', code => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
})

sp.stdout.on('end', function() {
  profile = parser.toJson(profile, { object: true })
  const installedBrowsers = jp
    .query(profile, 'plist.array.dict.array[1].dict[*].string[0]')
    .filter(item => browsers.indexOf(item) > -1)
  console.log(installedBrowsers)
  console.log('Finished collecting data chunks.')
})
```

Initial code:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
const sp = spawn('system_profiler', ['-xml', 'SPApplicationsDataType']);

sp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
    console.log(result)
  });
});

sp.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

sp.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, however this doesn't bring back information about installed browsers. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sry my mistake I should be a little more explicit. The system_profiler does give you all installed software you can check if the XML return contains a `google chrome`, `firefox` node and so on. You can test the return via the terminal with this command `system_profiler -xml SPApplicationsDataType`

Comment: Interesting. That does indeed give me all the apps installed, if I run it via the terminal. However, when run from my main.js file in my Electron app, I get a lot less results.

Comment: If you spawn a process you basically do the same as if you would type it into the terminal this is what the `sp` variable does. As you can imagine this will take up some time and could fail therefore sp has 3 event handlers for `stdout`, `stderr` and `close` if everything is ok the printed buffer is converted into a String and parsed via the data argument, xml2js will transfer it for you into a JavaScript Object which you can then check for the existance of the browser.

Comment: Oh is that so, this is strange since it should give you the same result. I have no Mac anymore so I had to code it blindly. could you try to print the string without parsing it to a object ? Maybe the parser does something wrong.

Comment: That results in lots of this: `<Buffer 65 6c 6f 70 65 72 3c 2f 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 0a 09 09 09 09 3c 6b 65 79 3e 70 61 74 68 3c 2f 6b 65 79 3e 0a 09 0
9 09 09 3c 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 2f 4c ... >`

Comment: that's a buffer you can transform it into a string via `data.toString('utf8')` 

Comment: Yep, found that out :) That does indeed now return the xml as in terminal, however xml2js is returning the same as before. I tried xml2json but that reports there's an error with the xml input. There's certainly something about the xml that these tools don't like. I suppose my alternative is to keep the xml output as a string and look for occurences of browser names.

Comment: Ah, I see. The output from stdout is chunked. I need a way to piece all the chunks together before sending them on to a parser.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, please tell me if you succeed with the parsing. 

Comment: Tested your code on my Mac at work, it does work there too. I'll add the chunking part to the answer, would be awesome if you could mark it as correct ;)

Comment: That's great. Copy my code over to your answer: I'll delete mine, and mark your answer as correct (as you did most of the work, and pointed me in the correct direction).

Comment: For the record, just tested on my work Mac and it works too. Thanks.

Comment: what about the same functionality under non-Mac OS? sorry bumping out of the topic.

Comment: @gumuruhyou could check the registry via powershell. BUT this will need more effort (For example windows apps like edge, or portables) something like `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*Firefox*' -or $_.DisplayName -like '*Chrome*'} | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: This basically returns a JSON of any software that _has a uninstaller_ (see my note above).